# Error pom.xml configuration with Spring Boot + Spring MVC + Primefaces + JoinFaces

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, joinfaces

I received error when try maven install command using STS IDE:

```
ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Paulo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.5.29\tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Paulo\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\javax.faces\2.3.4\javax.faces-2.3.4.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Paulo\.m2\repository\org\joinfaces\joinfaces-autoconfigure\3.2.0\joinfaces-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Paulo\.m2\repository\org\primefaces\primefaces\6.2\primefaces-6.2.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Paulo\.m2\repository\org\primefaces\extensions\primefaces-extensions\6.2.4\primefaces-extensions-6.2.4.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[INFO]
```

I downloaded basic project with spring boot and spring mvc from https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/
Runs fine.
After this I Add dependences of JoinFaces, but I recive error now.

My pom xml:

//Header omitted

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-serving-web-content</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <name>jsf-primefaces-spring-boot</name>
    <description>JSF - PrimeFaces Example using Spring Boot and Maven</description>
    <url>https://www.codenotfound.com/jsf-primefaces-example-spring-boot-maven.html</url>   
  <parent>   
    <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>joinfaces-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->       
  </parent>

  <properties>     
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

  </properties>  
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>          
        <!-- joinfaces -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
          <artifactId>primefaces-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>      
    </dependencies>  
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>   
</project>
```

Comment: I download dependencies again, but error persists

Comment: Your files are corrupt. Did you delete those files before re-downloading? If so, examine the actual files and see if they're something like an error message from a proxy instead of the real results.

Comment: Delete the faulty dependencies and run the maven build again, this happens sometime.